# How to get the full stacktrace while method is inline?

Tags: c#, .net

The question can be asked in another way, but I'm not sure which one is possible:

> How to force the runtime to disable method inline?

#### Problem

I have a library assembly (no source code), some methods are marked with `AggressiveInlining`:

**CSharpLib**

```
public class ExceptionTest
{
    private int[] a;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void A()
        => B();

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private void B()
        => a[0] = 1;
}
```

The assembly is built in Debug mode (with "Optimize code" unchecked).

In my program I need to call the method A:

**My program**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        new CSharpLib.ExceptionTest().A();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Even if the program is run in Debug mode, it only prints one line:

> at Program.Main(String[] args)

So I wonder if I can get a stacktrace with method `A` and `B` involved?

#### My attempts

Both `Environment.StackTrace` and `new StackTrace(true)` return the same one frame.

If I put a break point at the end of the catch block and watch `e.StackTrace` and `e`, The value of `e.StackTrace` is the same as above, but the value of `StackTrace` under `e` is full:

> at CSharpLib.ExceptionTest.B()
> at CSharpLib.ExceptionTest.A()
> at Program.Main(String[] args)

But I need log the stacktrace, so I cannot just refer the text here.

Comment: Remove the MethodImplAttribute? Or change it explicitly to NoInlining when creating a debug build (with an #if debug).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I don't have the source code, just a dll and a pdb.